# VBA Excel 2010 Run-time error'91' Object variable or With Block variable not set

Tags: excel, getelementbyid, vba

I've tried numerous tutorials and spent a lot of time on stack overflow trying to resolve this issue, but can never quite find the answer.

I'm new at VBA with excel, and have been trying to get an automated web search into excel that takes queries from one column of cells and writes an element from the results into another row of cells. To keep this example simple I used a Google search.

I always end up with the same message:

Run-time error'91' Object variable or With Block variable not set

[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XScFk.png)

Here is the lastest version of the code:

```
Sub Macro1()

 Dim ie As Object
 Set Rng = Range("A3:A5")

Set Row = Range(Rng.Offset(1, 0), Rng.Offset(1, 0).End(xlDown))

Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
With ie
    .Visible = True
    For Each Row In Rng
    .navigate "https://www.google.com/#q=" & Range("A" & Row.Row).Value

Do
    DoEvents
        Loop Until ie.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

        Dim doc As HTMLDocument
        Set doc = ie.document
        While ie.readyState <> 4

Wend

Range("B" & Row.Row) = doc.getElementById("resultStats" & Range("A" & Row.Row).Value).innerText

Next Row

ie.Quit

End With

End Sub
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Seems like `doc.getElementById("resultStats" & Range("A" & Row.Row).Value)` or `Range("A" & Row.Row)` probably evaluates to `Null`. Can you confirm that `Range("A" & Row.Row)` actually returns a non-null value and that there's a element in your HTML document that is actually named "resultStatsA?"

Comment: How about using proper indentation, so you can see which lines of code open a block and which close it? It will make your code easier to read and to troubleshoot.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it is not working, is because there is no element with the id named "resultStats**YOURVALUEHERE**" on Google. The `getElementById("resultStats")` will return the amount of results, e.g. 36,100,000 Results if you search for VBA on Google.
Furthermore, you should use `Option Explicit`.

If you want to return the "Header" and the "URL", you can do this. However, you can only have 1 value in A3 - but this can of course be amended.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Macro1()
Dim rng As Range, Cell As Range
Dim i As Integer
Dim IE As Object, objDiv As Object, objH3 As Object, objLink As Object
Dim strText As String

Set rng = Range("A3:A5")

Set Cell = Range(rng.Offset(1, 0), rng.Offset(1, 0).End(xlDown))

Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    With IE
        .Visible = False ' Change to True if you want to open IE and have it visible

        For Each Cell In rng
        .navigate "https://www.google.com/#q=" & Range("A" & Cell.row).value

        Do
            DoEvents
                Loop Until IE.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

                Dim doc As HTMLDocument
                Set doc = IE.document
                While IE.readyState <> 4
        Wend

            ' Add the 5 first results to rows
            For i = 0 To 4
                Set objDiv = doc.getElementById("rso")
                Set objH3 = objDiv.getElementsByTagName("H3")(i)
                Set objLink = objH3.getElementsByTagName("a")(0)

                strText = Replace(objLink.innerHTML, "<EM>", "")
                strText = Replace(strText, "</EM>", "")

                Dim CellRow As Integer
                If i = 0 Then
                    CellRow = Cell.row
                Else
                    CellRow = CellRow + 1
                End If

                ' Insert values starting in B3 and C3 and continue with B4, C4, for the next value etc.
                Cells(CellRow, 2) = strText
                Cells(CellRow, 3) = objLink.href
            Next i

        Next Cell

    IE.Quit

    End With
End Sub
```